# Possible to view field handles on entry type field definition page?

Tags: field, entry-type

When I am configuring the fields for a given entry type, is there a way to see those fields' handles on the same page? I often reference the entry type page to know which fields are associated with a given entry type, but then I have to cross reference the fields page to make sure I'm using the correct handle. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CP Field Links](https://github.com/mmikkel/CpFieldLinks-Craft) plugin to view the handles on the edit entry pages.

And it sounds like [this feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7194444-search-for-fields-and-show-field-handles-in-the-la) is very close to what you're asking for.  You might want to throw a vote its way.